# Auto complete suggestion box are not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

code:

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
  $return_arr = array();
  $term = $_GET['term'];
  $term = str_replace('.','',$term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM submission where keyword like '%".$term."%' or companyname like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN keyword LIKE '%".$term."%' THEN 1
  ELSE 2 END";
  $r = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
  {
    $key = explode(",", $row['keyword']);
    foreach ($key as $keyword) 
    {
      $return_arr[] = $keyword;
    }  
  }
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

[image]

In my code I have created a auto complete suggestion box and its working but it always showing wrong result if I write (i) it always show result with (a) alphabet why not (i) and also want to search with short name. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: If you get rid of the first % then it will NEED to start with i

Comment: Share example of searched result, if you have `aaai` then `ia`  it will display both and `aaai` will come first like `aaai,ia`

Comment: Your intent is: when you write (i) you want to results which are starts with (i) or is it enough that it contains (i). As a result it depns on your sql part that `...like '%i%'` or `... like 'i%'`

Comment: That ^ - because of the first `%` - ditch it!

Comment: @delboy1978uk is true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `%$term%` in your query. So whether the data store the searched keyword anywhere in the string, it will display to you. So if you want to search the data start with a specific character remove `%` from the start of your query to make it as `$term%` as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM submission where keyword like '".$term."%' or companyname 
like '".$term."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN keyword LIKE '".$term."%' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END";
```

Comment: No changes it return same result @RAUSHAN KUMAR :(

Comment: @omkara So basically what you want, the results came either containing that character, either starts with or either ends with?

Comment: I want result with starting character @RAUSHAN KUMAR

Comment: So if you press character `i` it will display results to you results where either keyword starts from `a` or companyname starts with `a`? Is it..?

Comment: can you add what output you are getting?

Comment: I have put image in my question please take a look @RAUSHAN KUMAR

Answer (score 3):

if you want to compare result `start with` input character then remove `%` from beginning

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM submission where keyword like '".$term."%' or companyname 
like '".$term."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN keyword LIKE '".$term."%' THEN 1
ELSE 2 END";
```

Comment: @omkara Are you sure you removed the preceding % in both like parts? Because in @"B. Desai"s solution the  `or companyname 
like '%".$term."%'` still has the preceding %.

Comment: luba is right I forgot to remove  `%` at one place try now

Comment: @omkara This is unrelated, but I also recommend in your case you use *ilike* to search case-insensitive.